# Updated text showing on another page

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

I build two pages, the first one should only be used by the admin, the second one has hard coded text that cannot be changed and can only be seen by the user for example. Im trying to make it so that when the admin updates the text, it gets displayed on the second page.
But im kinda lost right now. This is the admin page, the second page is basically the same, just with a hard coded Text.

```
class InformationContentDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  const InformationContentDetails({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override

  State<InformationContentDetails> createState() => _InformationContentDetails();
}
class _InformationContentDetails extends State<InformationContentDetails> {
  bool isEnable = false;
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  final _controller2 = TextEditingController();

  String name = "Information";
  String name2 = "Welcome";

  textlistener(){
    print("Update: ${_controller.text}");
    print("Update: ${_controller2.text}");

  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Start listening to changes
    _controller.addListener(textlistener);
    _controller2.addListener(textlistener);
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveBuilder(
      builder: (context, sizingInformation) {
        var textAlignment;
        if (sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.desktop) {
          textAlignment = TextAlign.left;
        } else {
          textAlignment = TextAlign.center;
        }

        return Container(
          width: 650,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                name,
                style: titleTextStyle(sizingInformation.deviceScreenType),
                textAlign: textAlignment,
              ),
              Container(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: "Update Information",
                  ),
                  controller : _controller,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: FlatButton(
                  child: Text('edit'),
                  onPressed:(){
                    setState((){
                      name = _controller.text;
                      isEnable = !isEnable;

                    });
                  },

                ),
              ),
              Text(
                name2,
                style: descriptionTextStyle(sizingInformation.deviceScreenType),
                textAlign: textAlignment,
              ),
              Container(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: "Update text"
                  ),
                  controller : _controller2,

                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: FlatButton(
                  child: Text('edit'),
                  onPressed:(){
                    setState((){
                      name2 = _controller2.text;
                      isEnable = !isEnable;

                    });
                  },

                ),
              ),


            ],
          )),
        );
      },
    );
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _controller2.dispose();
    super.dispose();


  }
}
```

Comment: You can add the text as arguments to the Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `sharedPreferences` since you said the second page is just read only

```
Container(
                child: FlatButton(
                  child: Text('edit'),
                  onPressed:()async{
                    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('Controller',  _controller2.text);
                    
                  },

                ),
              ),
```

in your next page just receive whatever value with

```
...
var valueController;
...
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

valueController = prefs.getString('Controller`);
```

use `valueController`